# Selecting multiple rows with Shift + Click and Shift + KeyDown on DBGrid

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I need to make code changes to my existing DBGrid component, such that rows are selected on Shift + Click and Shift + KeyDown. Here is what I have done so far for KeyDown:

```
if (Key = VK_DOWN)  and (ssShift in Shift) then
begin
       if not myDataset.Eof then
       begin
         myDataset.Next;
       end;
end;
```

But the above code does not select the entire row. It will only highlight the cell below it.
How do i modify this code, to select the entire row?
How can i do this for Shift+Click too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a couple of Options in your DBGrid:

- `dgRowSelect` = True
- `dgMultiSelect` = True

`dgRowSelect` means that the entire row, rather than a single cell, is selected.  The downside of this, which may not matter to you, is losing the ability to do an in-place edit in the grid.

Once you've made those changes, you'll find you don't need the code in your KeyDown handler.  In fact if you leave it in, you'll find that it skips every other row so you end up with a zebra-striped grid.

`dgMultiSelect' allow you to extend the select from a single row to more than one, by holding the Shift key at the same time as the Down or Up key.

However, you now say that you want in-place editing, which is incompatible with setting dgRowSelect to True.  The problem with that is that the scope for custom-drawing the cells of a DBGrid are somewhat limited without going to a *lot* of trouble, ime.  However, the following may be acceptable for your purpose.

In your grid, make sure `DefaultDrawing` is set to `True` and that the grid's `Options` are set like this:

```
Options = [dgEditing, dgTitles, dgIndicator, dgColumnResize, dgColLines, dgRowLines, dgTabs, dgConfirmDelete, dgCancelOnExit, dgMultiSelect]
```

You should find that when you click a row, the entire row is drawn "highlighted", not just the focused cell.  However, the in-place editor still works on the focused cell and you can still extend the row selection to more than one row using Shift + Up or Down.

Doing something with Shift + Click is, err, trickier.  I assume you want to extend the selection from the current row to the row you Shift-Click in?  I think you should post a separate q about that, because it's a different point.

Comment: I need to do in-place edit in the grid. So i cannot use dgRowSelect.

Comment: Pity you didn't mention that in your q.  Anyway, see the update to my answer.  What Delphi version are you using, btw?

Comment: Yes, my grid uses the same options as mentioned above. So I can see that even when in editable mode, I can select the entire row. I modified my code a little, and now select on down Arrow key press works. Setting grd.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True; works inside the code that I have written above.

Comment: Now, I am trying to figure out what function to use to capture the Click+Shift event. I am using Delphi 2007 btw.

Comment: Well, like I said, Shift+Click is another matter entirely and you'd do better to post that as a new q.

Comment: ok, just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260000/select-multiple-rows-on-shiftclick-in-dbgrid